# Using articles in a catch-phrase

Tags: word-usage, articles

I face an issue with a catch-phrase on my site.

English is not my native language, and I just can't solve this issue.

I have a catch-phrase, and by the rules of grammar, it needs the article *an*:

> Make test from your materials. Without **an** effort. Without wasting time

However, I have never seen this kind of usage of articles in slogans (or I just didn't notice), and it seems redundant to me.

Can I not include the article in the slogan, just because it is not a part of natural speech, and should be compact/strong? I mean, in order to sound certain, like "I'm loving it". By the way, is that also a formal mistake - to use *love* with *-ing*?

Comment: Actually, you don't need an article there. You could say, _"Without any effort, without wasting time."_ Alternatively (and perhaps improved): _"With very little effort, and without wasting time."_ If you want to be very compact, try a single word: _Effortlessly_.

Comment: Something like "(Make tests from your materials) *without wasting time or effort*" would sound better. But I don't really understand what you meant by "make test [sic]". The first sentence sounds very awkward and I can't make suggestions until I understand what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

"Effort" can be either a [countable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Count_noun) or [mass noun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_noun). In your case, you're referring to a quantity of effort, rather than a number of discrete efforts ­– so the most appropriate phrase would be "without effort".

On a side note: depending on exactly what you offer on your site, you're probably better off with "Build tests from your materials" rather than "Make test from your materials" (which is definitely wrong, and too ambiguous to be certain exactly what you want to say).

**Related:** [“The efforts involved” vs. “the effort involved”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/96586)